# Jenkins Zip file missing .gitignore and .gitattributes

Tags: jenkins

I'm attempting to use the archive functionality but I'm not able to download all the files. For example, in Jenkins I see:
[image]

However, after clicking the link to download all the files as a zip, then unzipping the files, I see:
[image]

I'm not sure why the .gitignore and .gitattributes are missing from the zip file when I download it but are present in the artifacts listed in Jenkins.

I use the following command to archive the artifacts:

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: "portfolios-deployment_${PACKAGE_VERSION}/**/*", onlyIfSuccessful: true, defaultExcludes: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`archiveArtifacts`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts) option:

> Archives the build artifacts (for example, distribution zip files or jar files) so that they can be downloaded later. Archived files will be accessible from the Jenkins webpage.

By that, it means it takes a copy of the artifacts from the workspace and stores them alongside the build logs on the controller. It is expected the workspace is ephemeral or its contents will be overwritten on next iteration, so they are preserved along with the logs, until the logs are deleted.

`archiveArifacts` has an **Advanced** ... option: 
**[ X ] Use default excludes**

If you expand the help, you'll see the details:

> Artifact archiver uses Ant org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner which
> excludes by default the following patterns:
> **/%*%,**/.git/**,**/SCCS,**/.bzr,**/.hg/**,**/.bzrignore,**/.git,**/SCCS/**,**/.hg,**/.#*,**/vssver.scc,**/.bzr/**,**/._*,**/#*#,**/*~,**/CVS,**/.hgtags,**/.svn/**,**/.hgignore,**/.svn,**/.gitignore,**/.gitmodules,**/.hgsubstate,**/.gitattributes,**/CVS/**,**/.hgsub,**/.DS_Store,**/.cvsignore
>
> This option allows to enable or disable the default Ant exclusions.

Turn that off and it should pick them up, but may also include much more. Consider using a pattern in:
**Files to archive [ **,.gitignore,.gitattributes ]**.

**Downloading**

However, the **"(all files in zip)"** is part of the Jenkins UI standard [DirectoryBrowserSupport](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/DirectoryBrowserSupport.html) capability. Any directory displayed within the "Browse Workspace" has the option displayed to download the content of that page. That **"(all files in zip)"** is also provided by the **[org.apache.tools.zip](https://ant.apache.org/manual/api/org/apache/tools/zip/package-summary.html)** capability which would use the same Ant FileSet excludes. This applies equally to both the **Browse Workspace** and **Browse Artifacts** pages. But, as this capability is built into the Jenkins UI layer, there does not seem to be any overrides for the Artifacts. You just need to download them manually individually.

It may be worth [filing a ticket (for component:core, label archive)](https://issues.jenkins.io/projects/JENKINS/issues) such that the download "all files in zip" respect the content as displayed within "Browse Artifacts". (That would not be desirable behaviour for the workspace itself).

---

**More generally:**

As the help says, it's based on [default Ant exclusions](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#defaultexcludes) (a list which [is modifiable](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/defaultexcludes.html)). See also [Ant FileSet](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) for other conventions.

Ant is in turn based in unix conventions, where files beginning with a dot "`.`" are "hidden files", typically considered "configuration files' and [not generally of interest](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/663401/121163). The Ant list is more specifically to exclude configuration files which are part of common source control systems (there'd be no need to continually archive `.git` for example). "dot files" do not show up by default in `ls -l`; you need to run `ls -la` (all). That logic also extend to other commands.

Also note that while unix is case sensitive, the default for Ant is "no" to case sensitivity for includes/excludes, which may cause issues if (for some silly reason) you have `Foo.java` and `foo.java`, but which is then enabled by default in the archiveArtifacts option.

Comment: Thanks, so I tried this and it doesn't solve the specific issue that I am facing. To clarify, the .gitignore and .gitattributes files are picked up and "appear" to live within the archive. I can see them inside of the of the jenkins build artifacts (take a look at the first screenshot). The issue is upon clicking the download zip link, downloading the zip file, and extracting it, there is no .gitignore or .gitattributes file. Somehow it seems like jenkins is configured to not include those files in the zip, even though they are included in the build artifacts archive.

Comment: Thank you. Disappointing but we do have a workaround here so this isnt critical.